# OAuth2 - How can I register my client application to get client_id and client_secret?

Tags: oauth-2.0, clientid

*Sorry for my English*

I can not find anything appropriate for search in Google on requests "*OAuth2 register client*" or "*OAuth2 get client id*".

Or maybe I'm bad looking?

**UPDATE:**

The application will access to some web-site, not to Google Services.

Comment: Are you trying to access a resource using Oauth, for example accessing the Facebook API?  Or are you trying to create your own Oauth access workflow for your own API?

Comment: Web-site will have own OAuth access workflow in the future. But other developer will implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You can register your application at https://cloud.google.com/console/

Click the Create project button and it should lead you though creating a new app.

The client id and Oauth information are set up under the

```
Apis & Auth -> credentials
```

Note: Don't forget to add the Branding information under Consent Screen.

Comment: I updated my question. I don't want to access to Google Services. I want to access to my web-site.

Comment: you want to make your own Oauth2 provider?  Or you want to allow people to login to your website using there Google login?

Comment: I want to make my own OAuth2 provider. But actually other developer will do it, because I'm developing Android client-application and I'm not familiar with client-side or web development

Comment: creating your own oauth2 provider depends a lot on the language your going to be doing it in.  I suggest you start goggling.